# naive spectral inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, laplacian

Consider the operator $H_0=-\Delta$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. The spectrum of $H_0$ is $\sigma(H_0)=\sigma_{ac}(H_0)=[0,+\infty)$.

I've been said that it is straightforward to show that if $I$ is an interval not containing $0$ then exist a constant $c>0$ such that $$E_I(H_0)H_0 E_I(H_0)\geq cE_I(H_0).$$
where $E(H_0)$ are the spectral projections (SP) of $H_0$.
Why is that?

I know this is a basic consequence of the relation between $H_0$ and its SP but I'm not totally confortable about how to handle SP under AC spectrum.

Comment: Can you prove this for a discrete spectrum?

Comment: Yes, I can. The action of the SP is clear in that case.

Comment: $E_I(H_0)f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^2\chi_I(\xi)\mathcal{F}f)$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Does your proof work if you (formally) replace sums over eigenprojections with integrals over the spectral measure? BTW, the owners of Questions/Answers are automatically notified, but for anyone else you have to put @username (followed by a space).

Comment: @KeithMcClary yes it does. thank you very much for your help Keith